# how do I restrict multiplicity and other properties in specialized classes using UML or class definitions

Tags: class, uml, diagram, modeling, specialization

I am trying to create a UML class diagram and corresponding class definition (in, for example, C# or Java) where I have a generic hierarchy of relationships and one or more specialized classes that are based on that general relationship but constrain it.

For example, say I have the following general UML relationships (pretend it looks like UML):

```
Router 
 <> 1
  |
  | * 
Card 
 <> 1
  |
  | *
Port
```

(Read as: Router contains 1 or more cards and each card contains one or more ports)

I then want to extend that and define a specialized class, for example CiscoRouter.

```
Router <|---CiscoRouter
```

Furthermore, let's say a CiscoRouter can only have have 1..10 cards. Is there a way to define this restriction in the model?

I could do something like the following:

```
Router <|---CiscoRouter
 <> 1           <> 1
  |              |
  | *            |
Card ____________|
 <> 1    10       
  |              
  | *            
Port
```

However, this would technically create two separate collections of Card objects, right? Any suggestions on how to best define this?

Actual designs will probably be more complicated as we will need classes like Cisco7200Router, LinkSysRouter, etc. As well as custom Cards, Ports, etc. For example:

```
Router <|---CiscoRouter
 <> 1           <> 1
  |              |
  | *            | 10
Card <|------CiscoCard
 <> 1           <> 1
  |              |
  | *            | 4
Port <|------CiscoPort
```

To add another complication, let's say that the Router has a property called Weight. However, in the CiscoRouter, we want to actually define that property to be a certain value, say 4 Lbs (e.g. our model somehow states that a CiscoRouter weighs 4 Lbs, has 10 cards, and each card has 4 ports). How do I define this?

I know I can do a lot of this in code using abstract classes, methods, etc; but I want to know if there is any clean way to define as much of this as possible in the model or metadata so that I can generate some design documentation from it without executing anything.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, that generally best way to express constraints on UML models when the semantics are not easily modeled by UML model elements is to use OCL constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion and in fact I just started exploring that possiblity. However, I am concerned that OCL itself is quite complex and not widely used. OCL constrains also seem a bit detached from the objects they constrain and I was hoping to find actual design practices that would help here.

Comment: OCL is fairly simple for simple tasks, especially when you can think in terms of OOP, lambda expressions, sets and predicates.

Comment: OCL is a standard and part of UML, I would say that most people are disappointed about tool support. In UML diagrams you can have constraints as something separate as well as connected with the object through special relationship. OCL constraints have context, which connects them to the model elements. When it comes to modeling it is best to choose tool which is best suited. You might model the constraint on cardinality as an attribute and check it dynamically, just as you would probably implement it. But that requires another diagram, which is more work than writing a simple constraint.